# Assign value to key in object based on previous values assigned to previous objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects that need to have a width value assigned to them based on the previous widths assigned to previous objects. The widths are predefined and need to add up to 100% for every four items in the array, the widths I am working with are as follows:

```
15%, 25%, 35%, 45%
```

so therefore there can only be certain combinations to ensure each row adds up to 100%, I know how to loop over the array and assign a random width value to each object just not sure how I would do it to ensure that each row equals 100%

Potential row combinations are:

```
15%, 15%, 25%, 45%
------------------
15%, 25%, 25%, 35%
------------------
25% + 25% + 25% + 25% (ideally would like to prevent this too to keep the rows as uneven as possible)
```

So far I have the following array of the possible sizes and a loop function that randomly selects a size and assigns it

```
    const tiles = [{id: 1, aspectRatio: ''}, {id: 2, aspectRatio: ''}, {id: 3, aspectRatio: ''}, {id: 4, aspectRatio: ''}, {id: 5, aspectRatio: ''}, {id: 6, aspectRatio: ''}, {id: 7, aspectRatio: ''}, {id: 8, aspectRatio: ''}
    const possibleSizes = ['15%', '25%', '35%', '45%'];
    let rowSizes = [];
    tiles.forEach((tile) => {
        const tileSize = sizes[Math.floor(Math.random() * sizes.length)];
        tile.aspectRatio = tileSize;
        if (rowSizes.length <= 3) {
            rowSizes.push(tileSize);
        } else {
            rowSizes = [];
        }
        console.log('rowSizes', rowSizes);
        console.log('tile', tile);
    });
```

So my question is how do I check the `rowSizes` array on each loop and ensure that it is equal to 100%?

Comment: what have you tried ?

Comment: @iwaduarte at the moment I am looping through the objects and storing the width values assigned to each in a seperate array however I don't know how I then reference that array to ensure the values being assigned add up to 100

Comment: Your condition is: _"The widths are predefined and need to add up to 100% for every four items in the array"_, yet you also say that `15%, 15%, 15%, 15%, 15%, 25%` is a potentional row combination. These cannot both be true.

Comment: Apologies @KIKOSoftware that's my mistake, you're right that is not a possible combination as that is too many items in a single row, question has been updated

Comment: Check your code, I get an error: *"tiles is not defined"*.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware tiles is an array pulled out of a json file and I hadn't included it in the code example as it's very long, will add an example to the question now

Comment: Ah, OK, well, I didn't know, I just tried to ran your code to see what it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that there should only be four columns, I think I would start with this:

```
15%, 15%, 15%, 15%
```

That makes a total of 60%, leaving us with 40% to share among these columns. I would do this by sharing 4 times 10% on a random column.

That would do the trick. In code that would be:

```
const sizes = [15, 15, 15, 15];
for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
   sizes[Math.floor(Math.random() * 4)] += 10;
}
console.log('sizes', sizes);
```

Note that I use numbers instead of strings. I assume this is no problem, because you can easily convert them to percentage strings.

**Do mind however:** You could, infrequently, get one column with 55%. If you don't want that you have to exclude those result, as you would the `[25, 25, 25, 25]` result.

Comment: I think the question may not have been clear, the column widths have to be one of the predefined sizes (15%, 25%, 35% or 45%), basically it needs to determine if there are two 15% columns already set, the next two will need to be 25% and 45%, or if there is two 25% columns set the remaining two would need to be 15% and 35% etc.

Comment: @Stuart: I think I did understand the question. Try running the code. When I do I get results like: `[25, 15, 35, 25]`, `[45, 15, 25, 15]` and `[35, 25, 15, 25]`. What's wrong with that?

Comment: Apologies KIKO, showing my ignorance, you're 100% right, thanks for the solution!

Answer (score 0):

Barring additional information (and the fact that this feels like a homework assignment), this seems to be a pretty good example of [The Coin Change Problem](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/understanding-the-coin-change-problem-with-dynamic-programming/), where the coins are substituted by your widths.

Seeing as it's a well-known and documented problem, with better explanations online than I could offer, I won't go into detail.

Another solution could be to use recursion - write a function that loops through all possible values, and then calls another instance of the function. The return condition is that you achieve 100% width, or no possible elements can be added without going over 100%.

Edit: Posted this answer before the original question was edited.

Comment: Not a homework assignment. Haven't heard of The coin change problem before, will check it out! Thanks